# What is a LINQ provider?

Tags: .net, linq

What is a "LINQ provider," and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A linq provider is software that implements the [`IQueryProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryprovider) and [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable) interfaces for a particular data store.  In other words, it allows you to write Linq queries against that data store.  For example, the [Linq to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview) provider allows you to write Linq queries against XML documents.

You can also write your own Linq provider, although it is not trivial.  See [Building an Iqueryable Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-series) and [Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I think that implementing IQueryable is a rather limited definition. You can use LINQ query expressions against *anything* that defines an appropriate Select method (it doesn't even need to implement any interfaces, because of compile time duck typing) or the other methods that are part of query expressions (Where, Join, GroupJoin, etc).

Answer (score 3):

> "LINQ (Language Integrated Query)
>   works as a middle tier between data
>   store and the language environment.
>   From a developer's point of view, it
>   is just a new pattern for querying
>   data from multiple data structures
>   directly in the IDE. Behind the scenes
>   it does a whole lot of tasks like
>   expression processing, validation and
>   calling the right routine to fetch
>   data or build a query to run in SQL
>   Server. In short, LINQ stands as
>   common query gateway between the
>   language and the data store."
>   http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/LINQProviderBasics.aspx

A particular gateway for a particular data store (e.g. xml files, sql rdmbs) *is* called a LINQ Provider. It is realised by implementing the IQueryable Interface.

Matt Waren has a great [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/) series on implementing a cusotm linq provider.

Comment: But what is a LINQ **Provider** was the question, no?