# Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals

Tags: c#, linq

Why do I get an argument exception saying I pass the wrong number of arguments to string.equals method?

I pass THREE arguments and that should be correct. Actually it should throw a compile time error not runtime...

Do you see the error?

```
var translations = await (from l in context.Languages
                  join t in context.Translations on l.ISO639_ISO3166 equals t.ISO639_ISO3166
                  where string.Equals(l.ApplicationName, applicationName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                  select new Translation
                  {
                      Key = t.Key,
                      Text = t.Text
                  }).ToListAsync();
```

UPDATE

```
Test Name:  GetTranslations
Test FullName:  TaaS.IntegrationTests.Tests.TranslationRepositoryTests.GetTranslations
Test Source:    C:\test\TaaS-WebApplication\TaaS.IntegrationTests\Tests\TranslationRepositoryTests.cs : line 17
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00,0473367

Result StackTrace:  
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetMethodBasedBinaryOperator(ExpressionType binaryType, Expression left, Expression right, MethodInfo method, Boolean liftToNull)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.LinqExpressionNormalizer.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression u)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.LinqExpressionNormalizer.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.LinqExpressionNormalizer.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter..ctor(Funcletizer funcletizer, Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.CreateExpressionConverter()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetResultsAsync>b__a()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TaaS.Repository.TranslationRepository.<GetTranslationsAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\_REPOSITORIES\taas-application\TaaS-WebApplication\TaaS.Repository\TranslationRepository.cs:line 20
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TaaS.IntegrationTests.Tests.TranslationRepositoryTests.GetTranslations() in C:\_REPOSITORIES\taas-application\TaaS-WebApplication\TaaS.IntegrationTests\Tests\TranslationRepositoryTests.cs:line 45
Result Message: 
Test method TaaS.IntegrationTests.Tests.TranslationRepositoryTests.GetTranslations threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'
```

Comment: Is `t.ISO639_ISO3166` a `string`?

Comment: is `l.ApplicationName` a string?

Comment: If they weren't strings. They would both be compile time errors. Elisabeth is seeing a runtime error.

Comment: Provide the full error.

Comment: @JBond Might as well get the easy stuff out of the way though, and having no information on the objects its good to make sure

Comment: Is the error for Boolean equals like the title says or string.equals as the question says?

Comment: t.ISO639_ISO3166 and l.ApplicationName are ALL strings. @user I updated my question with the full exception.

Comment: @Elisabeth good. As you can see the full error details allowed someone to post a correct answer. Interpreting the full error message is the first step to debugging. Note, that the error clearly tells you that this is an Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL problem. `System.Data.Entity`...

Comment: I didn't need the stacktrace; I've just finally learned this pattern!

Comment: SQL string comparisons *are* case-invariant. Why are you using `Equals` in the first place?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it depends on your collation setting.

Comment: @codekaizen which typically is *not* case-sensitive.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos perhaps in your experience, yes, but it is dangerous to generalize, especially given this is a translation application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a runtime error because you are likely running against a [Linq query provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568039/what-is-a-linq-provider), which takes an [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) the C# compiler created from your C# code and executes it at runtime. The provider likely can't translate this overload of Equals.

Try changing your Linq query to be:

```
(from l in context.Languages
join t in context.Translations on l.ISO639_ISO3166 equals t.ISO639_ISO3166).AsEnumerable()
.Where(l => string.Equals(l.ApplicationName, applicationName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
.Select(new Translation
              {
                  Key = t.Key,
                  Text = t.Text
              }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: While this is the correct answer, is there any list of a functions that are required to be supported by **any** Linq query provider? I know about `Canonical Functions`, but AFAIK they are EF specific. Many people get confused when switching from `IEnumerabe<T>` to `IQueryable<T>` - everything happily compiles and then they start getting those runtime errors.

Comment: It depends on the provider.

Comment: I see. So nothing similar to ANSI SQL like ECMA LINQL :-) Thanks.

Comment: @codekaizen copy/paste your code I can not make it compile.

Comment: I changed the comparison to "==" because that is what I wanted remembering again that the sql comparison is case insensitive thanks to @Panagiotis Kanavos.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. The string.Equals mentioned is still the version that is not supported by Entity Framework.

Comment: This is not a good answer because `AsEnumerable()` loads **all** rows in memory, then tries to apply the `WHERE` condition without any benefit of indexing. Instead of loading eg 10 rows from a 100K table, it will load all 100K rows

Comment: @IvanStoev this is not the correct answer, actually it's a common bug - switching to Enumerable executes the query and loads everything in memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos While you are right in general, looks like EF Core consider loading whole tables in memory not a bug, but feature - it does that by default for any expression it cannot translate to SQL :)

Comment: @IvanStoev source? Because it does no such thing. You can't load data from a database without SQL - SQL Server doesn't listen to anything *except* SQL. You can easily verify this by using SQL Server Profiler. Perhaps you confuse EF Core with the planned (but not released) NoSQL support?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, I meant the LINQ query not fully translated to SQL like in EF6. But something like the above, only made automatically for you :) See, I'm kidding, but it's really a big problem, and MS team made it a default feature. They call it mixed query execution or something like that.

Comment: While this may work, this is the wrong solution. Since SQL string comparisons are already case insensitive, simply doing a `l.ApplicationName == applicationName` comparison will do a case insensitive compare, because the LINQ expression will just be translated into a SQL statement. The error is happening by DESIGN, don't try to "make it work".

Comment: @Sergey SQL string comparison is not always case insensitive. The database collation determines this.

Comment: Yep, good point @codekaizen. Maybe the answer can be updated to mention that.

Answer (score 31):

First of all, SQL string comparisons are case-insensitive, or rather, the most common collations are case-insensitive.

You shouldn't need to use `String.Equals` at all. Try executing your query *without* the `String.Equals` call.

If, for some reason, the query fails to return results, there may be a problem with the arguments or the data. You should try to execute the equivalent SQL statement directly and check whether there *are* any matching results.

String case would be an issue only if the underlying column's collation was modified to a string-sensitive one. This would be  *very* unusual. In fact, the difficult part is getting LINQ to EF to do a case-*sensitive* query.

As for the error itself, it's caused because `String.Equals` can't be translated to SQL. LINQ by itself *doesn't* execute queries, it's just a language. LINQ providers are responsible for translating queries to the underlying language and executing them.

Some providers, like LINQ to SQL, will parse whatever they can, load the result in memory and pass it to LINQ to Object for the unsupported operations. This typically results in *very* bad performance. In your case, your query would load all translations in memory and then try to filter them.

LINQ to EF on the other hand doesn't allow this to prevent performance problems. Queries that can't be translated, aren't executed. `String.Equals` in particular can't be translated to SQL as string comparisons are controlled by culture-specific collations. There is no equivalent to the Invariant Culture.

If your table *is* case-sensitive, you'll have to change the collation used for comparisons, eg to `Latin1_CI_AS`. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison) describes various ways to do that

Comment: Thanks for the case-insensitive comment. That really helped!

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct. However, I find it slightly annoying. Code First should not be making so many assumptions about the database that you can put .Where(a == b) as a C# condition and expect it to match where a and b aren't the same case. C# rules should apply regardless.

Comment: @StephenHolt it's LINQ to EF, not Code First. Furthermore, it's making *fewer* assumptions precisely to avoid generating unexpectedly bad queries, like LINQ to SQL did. Finally, trying to apply C# rules to a completely different language is a recipe for performance bugs. LINQ isn't C# specific to begin with.

Comment: @StephenHolt In SQL's case, it would be a disaster because collation is *column* specific. It affects *indexing*. Trying to use a different collation invalidates indexes and results in full table scans

Comment: @StephenHolt, since we are talking about translations, different languages have very different matching rules between upper and lower case. The Turkish I is the perfect example - there are [dotted and dotless variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I)

Comment: @StephenHolt - I wonder if, to achieve what you'd like to see, you could do `.ToList().Where(a == b)`?  Haven't tried it, just suggesting.  I'd imagine that brings evaluation of `Where` into LINQ to Object.

Comment: @OutstandingBill yes, I imagine that would work. By calling ToList() you're bringing the processing of the conditional in-house, and it will be processed using C# rules. It's not necessarily a good thing to do, though, because it will cause the whole set to be loaded from DB into memory before applying the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

In Linq you need to use the static method of equals. Do this instead and it will work:

```
where l.ApplicationName.Equals(applicationName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Isn't this still too many arguments? :( ... I still get the error by changing to Invariant.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (if you insist on case insensitive comparison)

```
var translations = await (from l in context.Languages
                  join t in context.Translations on l.ISO639_ISO3166 equals t.ISO639_ISO3166
                  where l.ApplicationName.Equals(applicationName,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                  select new Translation
                  {
                      Key = t.Key,
                      Text = t.Text
                  }).ToListAsync();
```

Note:

```
l.ApplicationName.Equals(applicationName,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

But most likely you don' t need this as Linq to SQL is by default

> "..case-insensitive, or rather, the most common collations are
>   case-insensitive..."

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way of case-insensitive comparison if you can opt this:

```cs
where l.ApplicationName.ToLower() == applicationName
```

where `applicationName` can be passed as `applicationName.ToLower()` so this becomes case-insensitive comparison :P